# textbox.text always returning empty string instead of user's entered text

Tags: asp.net

I am very surprised to see last night my code was working fine and the next day suddenly my textbox.text always have empty string..
My code is:

```html
 Name of Event* :

    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
} 

protected void create_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    if (!object.Equals(Session["UserLoginId"], null)) { 

        int mid = 0; 
        int cid = 0; 
        bool valid = true;

        if (this.TextBox1.Text == "") {

            error.Text = "<p style='color:red'>Marked Fields are compulsory!!</p>"; 

        }

        else { 
            .... // database insert .... 
        }
```

I am always ending up with an error.text value.

Why?

Comment: I suspect there's something more happening here in code that isn't included.  Maybe there's something in `Page_Load` which is clearing the `TextBox`?

Comment: there might be multiple form tag in your app in asp.net webform only one form tag allow check that

Comment: @ImranRashid Exactly the same problem ruined my whole day.. a form tag with runat=server attribute was present in the master page, first I was getting empty values in code behind.. and then I ended up with two server side form tags error! :/

Answer (score 5):

Had a similar problem with text boxes getting cleared on adding a new row.  It was the issue of the page reloading when the add button was clicked.

Fixed the issue by adding:

```
Sub Page_Load
  If Not IsPostBack Then 
    BindGrid()
  End If
End Sub
```

Per Microsoft's documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478966.aspx.

Answer (score 3):

Kinda mentioned but you should make sure your checking your that Post_Back event is not clearing your textbox. It would by default.
Try something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (this.TextBox1.Text == "")
            {
                error.Text = "<p style='color:red'>Marked Fields are compulsory!!</p>";
            }
        else
        {
            //.....
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not Working!!
And i have figured out the reason but don't know actually why this is happening
I have changed my master file and with the new master file designing its not working else the code is fine and working, i have checked it.

Now why the new master file is making asp textbox to lose state afterpostback...????

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I had a textarea feeding data to a database on postback. I also designed the page to populate the textarea from the same database field. The reason it failed was because I forgot to put my reload logic inside an `if(!IsPostPack) {}` block. When a post back occurs the page load event gets fired again and my reload logic blanked the textarea before I could record the initial value.

Answer (score 1):

If the page make a post back, then all the data , the user entered ,will be erased,as the controls are stateless, so u should keep your data entry through EnableViewState = true.

Comment: @gitesh - add this code to your question. If nothing else it will be formatted better.

Comment: I am not doing anything in Page_Load

Comment: is `create`  your button? , please post the `aspx` of the button,and i wanna to know if u use update panel or not?

Comment: may be some probabilities:
`1- you enter no data.
2- there is some validation .
3- you empty the textbox some where.`
if u could ctrl+F to find all references of this textbox to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

I am having this issue, but i'm using Telerik Ajax request with target in javascript. I have a RadTextBox and a RadButton. I call the same code from both of them but if i call it from the textBox and request a postback, the textbox is empty in the page load. So i call `RadAjaxManager.ajaxRequestWithTarget('someUserControlClientID', 'myTextBoxText');`
So in the page_load, i can grab the text, in case it's not sent to the server with the arguments sent, `Request.Form("__EVENTARGUMENT")` will hold my textBox value.
by the way, RadAjaxManager.ajaxRequestWithTarget is like `__doPostBack('targetID', 'arguments');`. Hope this helps someone. I don't have time to investigate why i lose the text with this request, so this is the workaround i did.